# how to limit input in while loop need serious looking into

Tags: python, while-loop

how can i limit the input for srj imbetween 1 and 0 and it just restarts the whole program

```
def gen0():      # input all the initial data
    while True:  # this will loop infinitely if needed
        try:     # this will try to take a float from the user
            j=int(input('how many juveniles are there in generation 0? '))
            srj=float(input('what is the survival rate of juveniles '))
            break             # if the user gives a number then break the loop
        except ValueError:    #if the user does not give a number then the user will be told to retry
            print("Sorry, there was an error. Please enter a positive number")
```

Comment: Based on your comments, what you want is to re-request only the one piece of info which was invalid, and keep the other.  I would suggest that you simply DO THAT.  Loop on j until it is good.  Loop on srj until it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are breaking within a `try`/`except`, you can simple `raise` a `ValueError` if the data is incorrect.

```
if  srj > 1.0 or srj < 0.0:
    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score -2):

put the if statement `if srj > 1 or srj < 0:gen0()` before the `break` line
:^)

Comment: it works perfectly but if you enter wrong imput it restarts program

Comment: No need to call gen0(). It already has while True.  Just don't break if you don't want it to break.  Also it might be polite to print a message like "It takes two to tango."

Comment: def gen0():#input all the initial data
    while True:#this will loop infinitely if needed
        try:#this will try to take a float from the user
            j=int(input('how many juveniles are there in generation 0? '))
            srj=float(input('what is the survival rate of juveniles '))
            if srj > 1 or srj < 0:gen0()
            break#if the user gives a number then break the loop
        except ValueError:#if the user does not give a number then the user will be told to retry
            print("Sorry, there was an error. Please enter a positive number")